# generating own btf format for kernel structures in libbpf bpf programs

Tags: clang, libbpf

Tracing project may need to run on Linux kernels that may not have vmlinux.
I am aware of https://github.com/aquasecurity/btfhub away ( not allowed to used this).
Currently project access very few kernel data structure members, willing to have maintain structs  with minimal fields. please let me know any issues with this approach.

Is this correct way to build own btf format, One observation is that without struct variable declaration, command not generating btf fomat, is this requirement ? i.e task1

clang -c -g -O2 -target bpf t1.c

bpftool btf dump file t1.o format c

```
#ifndef __VMLINUX_H__
#define __VMLINUX_H__

#ifndef BPF_NO_PRESERVE_ACCESS_INDEX
#pragma clang attribute push (__attribute__((preserve_access_index)), apply_to = record)
#endif

struct task_struct {
        int pid;
        char comm[16];
};

    #ifndef BPF_NO_PRESERVE_ACCESS_INDEX
    #pragma clang attribute pop
    #endif
    
    #endif /* __VMLINUX_H__ */
    
    t1.c
    struct task_struct {
        int pid;
        char comm[16];
    }task1;        // without task1, bpftool dumping without struct 
    
    int man()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```